# How to directly assign the SOLE hash key to a scalar in perl

Tags: perl, hash

Is it possible to assign the *only existing* hash key *directly* to a scalar?

For example can these two statements be combined into one?

```
@the_keys = keys %the_hash;       # a hash with a single key
$the_sole_key = shift @the_keys;
```

The existence of a single key in `%the_hash` has been verified in preceding code.

Answer (score 7):

```
my ($key) = keys(%hash);
```

or

```
my $key = ( keys(%hash) )[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Two additional one-liners.
Is there an argument for preferring one of these solutions over the others? For instance,
do any of these solutions take less time or use fewer computing resources?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
use feature 'say';
my%stuff=('06'=>'fly',);
print Dumper\%stuff;
my $what;
say 'extract from anonymous array :';
$what=[keys%stuff]->[0];say$what;
say 'join list:';
$what=join '',keys%stuff; say$what;
say 'remove parentheses from earlier-posted solution :';
($what)=keys%stuff; say$what;
say 'remove parentheses from 2nd earlier-posted solution :';
$what=(keys%stuff)[0];say$what;
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123845/2227743) rather than a new answer.

Comment: @EricAya I do provide two more solutions, though.